# mean is not 0 after Normalize (Torchvision)

Tags: pytorch, floating-point, precision, normalize, torchvision

I am trying to understand `Normalize()` from `Trochvision.transforms`. After using it, the `mean` should be `0` and the `std()` should be `1`. At least that's what the tutorials tell. But it does not work!

I tried this code:

```py
tensor = torch.Tensor([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]])
normalize = transforms.Normalize(3.5, 1.7838) # used tensor.mean(), tensor.std()
norm_tensor = normalize(tensor)
```

The output is

- `norm_tensor.mean()`: `tensor(-4.9671e-09)`
- `norm_tensor.std()`: `tensor(1.0000)`

Shouldn't the mean be exactly `0` instead of `-4.9671e-09`? I tried googling and found a few tutorials, as for example [this](https://www.binarystudy.com/2021/09/how-to-normalize-pytorch-tensor-to-0-mean-and-1-variance.html). Strangely enough they **get `3.4769e-08`** but write "Yes!!!! Our Tensor is **normalized to 0 mean** [...]"

Do I miss some understanding or is "close to 0" and not `0` the correct normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is due to floating point subtraction [*].

Consider the following:

```
1 - 1/3 - 2/3
```

output:

```
>>> 1 - 1/3 - 2/3
1.1102230246251565e-16
```

This is because [floating point subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) is inaccurate. By inaccurate, I mean it loses [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). When you subtract two numbers which are "close", you usually won't get exactly 0.

Since normalization requires subtraction (by the mean), you won't get exactly zero, as each element has some error from the ideal value had it been subtracted the exact ideal mean.

The calculated-mean itself is also not exactly the ideal, actual mean, though this is less likely to be the main cause of error.

---

The question is, why do you NEED it to be exactly zero?

---

- I *assume* this is the reason, but admittedly have not looked at the actual code.

---

You will notice `1 - 1/2 - 1/4 - 1/4 == 0`, because of how numbers are represented, though with a bit of effort, we could "break" such numbers too.

Example

```
>>> 1e50 - 2e49 - 4e49 -4e49
1.0384593717069655e+34
>>> 1e20 - 2e19 - 4e19 -4e19
0.0
```

---

Bottom line, don't sweat so much about getting exact results when working with floating point numbers. Since you are working with digital computers, you have to compromise on accuracy, to a degree.

There are libraries that don't have these problems, which are purely software. They will be much slower because of this.

Comment: I don't need it to be exactly zero. The tutorials just always describe it that way, instead of saying "approximately zero". 

Thank you very much for this detailed answer. That helps my understanding a lot!